# Why paste chart using CK editor and when view from page, it is not nicely display?

Tags: php, html, sql, ckeditor

Am new to PHP. Finally create a page for user to input updates. When my user insert in a chart nicely view in the CK editor, but when view the form from page, it goes all the way down to the bottom leaving a big gap in the center?

How can I write the PHP code so that it will adjust the chart size automatically to be fit into the form nicely? 
Here is a sample of how the photo looks like.

When I post the chart....
[image]

When I view the chart after post, there is a big gap as see from arrow draw...

[image]

Here is my php code.

```
<?php require_once("Includes/DB.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("Includes/Functions.php"); ?>
<?php require_once("Includes/Sessions.php"); ?>
<?php $SearchQueryParameter=$_GET["id"]; ?>
<?php
if (isset($_POST["Submit"]))
{
    $Name = $_POST["CommenterName"];
    $Email = $_POST["CommenterEmail"];
    $Comment = $_POST["CommenterThoughts"];
    date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Singapore");
    $CurrentTime=time();
    $DateTime=strftime("%B-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S",$CurrentTime);

    if(empty($Name)||empty($Email)||empty($Comment))    {
        $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "All fields must be filled out";
        echo "FullPost.php?id=$SearchQueryParameter";
        Redirect_to("FullPost.php?id={$SearchQueryParameter}");
    } elseif (strlen($Comment)>500) {
        $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"] = "Comment length should be less than 500 characters";
        Redirect_to("FullPost.php?id={$SearchQueryParameter}");
    } else {

    // Query to insert comment in DB when everything is fine
     global $ConnectingDB;
     $sql = "INSERT INTO comments(datetime,name,email,comment,approvedby,status,post_id)";
     $sql .="VALUES(:dateTime,:name,:email,:comment,'Pending','OFF',:postIdFromURL)";
     $stmt = $ConnectingDB->prepare($sql); // - > means PDO object rotation
     $stmt->bindValue(':dateTime',$DateTime);
     $stmt->bindValue(':name',$Name);
     $stmt->bindValue(':email',$Email);
     $stmt->bindValue(':comment',$Comment);
     $stmt->bindValue(':postIdFromURL',$SearchQueryParameter);
     $Execute=$stmt->execute();
      // var_dump($Execute); This sentence is good for troubleshooting use

     if($Execute)
        {
            $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"]="Comment submitted Successfully";
            Redirect_to("FullPost.php?id={$SearchQueryParameter}");

        } else {
            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="Something went wrong, please try again";
            Redirect_to("FullPost.php?id={$SearchQueryParameter}");
         }
         //Query to inser category in DB when everything is fine
   }
  }
   //Ending of Submit Button If- Condition
   ?>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang="en">
  <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" 
 integrity="sha384-fnmOCqbTlWIlj8LyTjo7mOUStjsKC4pOpQbqyi7RrhN7udi9RwhKkMHpvLbHG9Sr" 
 crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" 
 href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384- 
 ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/Styles.css">
        <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>

         <title>Full Post Page</title>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div style="height:10px; Background:#27aae1;"></div>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <div class="container" ">
            <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"> Application Department </a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarcollapseCMS">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarcollapseCMS">

            <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">

                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="Content.php" class="nav-link"><i class="fas fa-home text-success"></i> 
Home </a>
                </li>
    <!--            <li class="nav-ite m">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link"> About Us </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="Content.php" class="nav-link"> Content</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Contact Us</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link">Features</a>
                </li>   --->
            </ul>
                <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                    <form class="form-inline d-none d-sm-block" action="Content.php">
                        <div class="form-group">
                        <input class="form-control mr-2" type="text" name="Search" 
placeholder="Search here"value="">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary" name="SearchButton">Go</button>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
        <div style="height:10px; Background:#27aae1;"></div>
        <!--NAVBAR END-->
 <!--header-->
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row mt-4">
            <!--Main area start-->
            <div class="col-sm-7">
                <h1> Technical Information Blog </hl>
                <h1 class="lead"> The complete Technical information library by Application 
Department</h1>
                <?php
                echo ErrorMessage();
                echo SuccessMessage();
                ?>
                <?php
                global $ConnectingDB;
                //SQL query when search button is active
                if(isset($_GET["SearchButton"])){
                    $Search = $_GET["Search"];
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts
                    WHERE datetime LIKE :search
                    OR author LIKE :search
                    OR title LIKE :search
                    OR category LIKE :search
                    OR customername LIKE :search
                    OR post LIKE :search";
                    $stmt = $ConnectingDB-> prepare($sql);
                    $stmt->bindValue(':search','%'.$Search.'%');
                    $stmt->execute();

                }
                // The default SQL query
                else{
                    $PostIdFromURL = $_GET["id"];
                    if (!isset($PostIdFromURL)) {
                            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="Bad Request !";
                            Redirect_to("Content.php");

                    }
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE id= '$PostIdFromURL'";
                    $stmt=$ConnectingDB->query($sql);
                    $Result=$stmt->rowcount();
                    if ($Result!=1) {
                        $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="Bad Request!";
                        Redirect_to("Content.php?page=1");

                    }

                }

                while ($DataRows=$stmt->fetch()) {
                    $PostId = $DataRows["id"];
                    $DateTime = $DataRows["datetime"];
                    $PostTitle = $DataRows["title"];
                    $Category = $DataRows["category"];
                    $Admin = $DataRows["author"];
                    $Customer = $DataRows["customername"];
                    $PostDescription = $DataRows["post"];
                 ?>
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h4 class="card-title"><?php echo htmlentities($PostTitle); ?> </h4>
                        <small> Written by <?php echo htmlentities($Admin); ?>  for <a 
href="Content.php?customername=<?php echo htmlentities($Customer);?>"><?php echo 
htmlentities($Customer); ?></a> under <a href="Content.php?category=<?php echo 
htmlentities($Category); ?>"> <?php echo htmlentities($Category); ?></a> On <?php echo 
htmlentities($DateTime); ?>  </small>

                        <hr>
                        <p class="card-text">
                            <?php echo nl2br($PostDescription); ?> </p>

                    </div>
            </div>
            <br>

        <?php } ?>


        <!-- Comment Part Start -->
        <!-- Fetching existing comment START -->
            <span class="FieldInfo">Comments</span>
            <br><br>
        <?php
        global $ConnectingDB;
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE post_id='$SearchQueryParameter'AND status='ON'"; // Show 
only if status is ON. Else if no need approve, just remove the status.
        $stmt =$ConnectingDB->query($sql);
        while ($DataRows = $stmt->fetch())  {
            $CommentDate = $DataRows['datetime'];
            $CommenterName = $DataRows['name'];
            $CommentContent = $DataRows['comment'];

        ?>

        <div>
            <div class="media CommentBlock">
                <img class="d-block img-fiuld align-self-start" src="images/comment.png" alt="">
                <div class="media-body m1-2">
                    <h6 class="lead"><?php echo $CommenterName; ?></h6>
                    <p class="small"><?php echo $CommentDate; ?></p>
                    <p><?php echo $CommentContent; ?></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
    <?php } ?>
        <!-- Fetching existing comment END -->


        <div class="">
                <form class="" action="FullPost.php?id=<?php echo $SearchQueryParameter?>" 
method="post">
                    <div class="card mb-3">
                        <div class="card-header">
                                <h5 class="FieldInfo">Share your thoughts about this post</h5>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class ="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user"></i> 
 </span>
                                    </div>
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" name="CommenterName" 
 placeholder="Name" vaue="">
                            </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="form-group">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <div class ="input-group-prepend">
                                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-university"> 
 </i></span>
                                    </div>
                                <input class="form-control" type="email" name="CommenterEmail" 
 placeholder="Region (DHS,DHKL etc)" vaue="">
                            </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <textarea name="CommenterThoughts" class="form-control" rows="8" 
  cols="70"> </textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="">
                            <button type="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit 
 </button>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                </form>

        </div>
        <!-- MainArea End-->

        <!--Side Area End-->
        <!-- Side Area Start -->

        <div class="col-sm-4" >  <!--style=min-height:40px; background:green; can add more thing 
  behind here for style-->
            <div class="card mt-4">
                <div class="text-center">
                    This is Application Department Technical information sharing page. Hope you can 
  learn something from here
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <a button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-block text-center text-white 
  mb-4" href="Login.php" name="button">Login </a></button>
                </div>
            </div>

        <br>
        <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header bg-primary text-light">
                    <h2 class="lead">Categories</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <?php
                        global $ConnectingDB;
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM category ORDER BY id desc";
                        $stmt=$ConnectingDB->query($sql);
                        while ($DataRows=$stmt->fetch()) {
                            $CategoryId = $DataRows["id"];
                            $CategoryName=$DataRows["title"];

                         ?>
                         <a href="Content.php?category=<?php echo $CategoryName; ?>"> <span 
 class="heading"> <?php echo $CategoryName; ?></span><br>
                     <?php }  ?>

             </div>
        </div>
        <br>
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header bg-info text-white">
            <h2 class="lead"> Recent Posts </h2>
        </div>
        <div class="card-body">
            <?php global $ConnectingDB;
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM posts ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 0,5";
            $stmt=$ConnectingDB->query($sql);
            while ($DataRows=$stmt-> fetch())
            {
                $Id     = $DataRows['id'];
                $Title = $DataRows['title'];
                $DateTime = $DataRows['datetime'];
                $Author = $DataRows['author'];

                ?>
                <div class="media-body m1-2">
                <a href="FullPost.php?id=<?php echo htmlentities($Id); ?> "target="_blank"> <h6 
  class="lead"><?php echo htmlentities($Title);?></h6></a>
                    <p class="middle"><?php echo htmlentities($Author);?> </p>
                    <p class="small"><?php echo htmlentities($DateTime); ?> </p>
                </div>

                <hr>
            <?php   } ?>
        </div>
        </div>
        <!-- Side Area End -->
  </div>
        </div>
    </div>

<!--header end-->
<!--footer -->
<footer class="bg-dark text-white">
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
        <p class="lead text-center"> Create by : Evelyn | <span id="year"></span> &copy; ---All right 
 Reserved.</p>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
 </footer>
    <div style="height:10px; Background:#27aae1;"></div>
<!--End footer -->

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384- 
q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" 
integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" 
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$('#year').text(new Date().getFullYear());

</script>

</body>


</html>
```

Can any kind soul advise me what's wrong with my code please? How to have the chart fit in nicely?

Thank you so much.

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? It should not be too hard to check the rendered markup using your browser's developer tools to check where that gap comes from

Comment: Sorry I did not use any tool to debug the problem. As new to this PHP, any advise how should I debug to solve it please?